# parsing '\L' - Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, regex

To be honest, I can't understand why I'm getting this error. The test below fails with the folllowing message:

> Failed: System.ArgumentException : parsing '\L' - Unrecognized escape
>   sequence \L. System.ArgumentException : parsing '\L' - Unrecognized
>   escape sequence \L.

This happens despite fact that all online regex testers show full match result. Am I not escaping the "\" character correctly here?

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void LineMathesRegex()
        {
            string line = "\\L";

            bool result = Act("\\L", line);

            Assert.True(result);
        }

        private bool Act(string regexExpression, string line)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(regexExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            return regex.IsMatch(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two backslashes to get the correct regex string if you want to match the literal string "\L". Otherwise, the regex engine is going to try to parse "\L" as an escape sequence, as your error is showing. Since you want to escape the backslash for matching literally, you can either enter two escaped backslashes, like so:

```
bool result = Act("\\\\L", line);
```

Or you can use a verbatim string

```
bool result = Act(@"\\L", line);
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why?

Comment: @aspdev Sure, I've added a bit on what's happened. Essentially, the string you're passing is interpreted the same as "\L" once it's read in by Regex engine, which it believes to be an escape sequence that does not exist-The solution is to make sure the string you pass in is "\\L", so the engine interprets the backslash as escaped.